# Best way to getdata from server to mobile apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, xamarin

Maybe this seems like and opinion question, but what I really need to know if I'm doing my job in a secure and good performance way or not.

I develop a lot of mobile apps (based on xamarin), who get data from local servers (windows server) from dbf files.

What I have done is develop some asp.net webservices (asmx) to get the data from the dbf files and send it to my apps by json (I like c#, that's why asp.net).

Then we get a static address to our customer, install IIS, deploy the webservice and the app conects to it. We redirect the port 80 from the router to the server and all works.

I use some basic encryption to the json, and the apps have user and password.

As I say at the start my question is if that's a correct aproach, or it can be done in a different and more secure way (and performance, but I'm mostly worried abour security), I don't have a lot of experience with servers.

Comment: Have you tried to obtain data the opposite way?
1, On the server you have ASP.NET WebAPI (similar to your asp.net webservices)
2, the mobile device using Xamarin WebClient inquires via https url on your WebAPI and that it returns data in JSON.
So your mobile app start getting data and you can use HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Mmmm... I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET WebApi and WebClient with HTTPS protocol

On client side (mobile device or other) :

```
string result = "";
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string apiUrl = string.Format(@"https://webapi.yourdomain.com/api/{0}/{1}/", model.UserName, model.UserPass);
    webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    result = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri(apiUrl));
}
ResponseMyObj resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseMyObj >(result);
```

On server side (ASP.NET WebApi) :

```
public class MyObjController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetMyObjList")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMyObjList(string UserName, string UserPass)
    {//Here you can check the credentials and retrieve data from the database and return them back to the client...
        object result = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I didn't get any other answer I would think your sugestion is the only option to get better security